# Tailwind css translate-y-full does not work

Tags: transform, tailwind-css

Here is an original code from compiled TailwindCSS file:

```
.translate-y-full {
  --transform-translate-y: 100%; 
}
```

It does not work. The syntax of CSS is incorrect. When I changed it to:

```
.translate-y-full {
  transform: translateY(100%);
  /* --transform-translate-y: 100%; */
}
```

It started to work.

Maybe I am missing something but it seems to be bug and a big one...???

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Add `transform` to the classes.

`<img class="transform translate-y-full" ...>`

Comment: This did not seem to work for me. Do you remember which tailwind version you were using or what the `transform` utility class is supposed to do?

Answer (score 11):

Maybe you forgot to put this line below in your css codes

```css
@tailwind base;
```

Comment: This is what I was missing! Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to make this work without importing @tailwind base? As I am using a component library right now which implicitly says not to import base if using with tailwind.

Comment: You need to set `corePlugins: { preflight: false }` in `tailwind.config.js`: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#disabling-preflight

Answer (score 3):

Tailwind (I'm using version `3.2.7`) uses the following css for the `.translate-y-full` utility class:

```css
.translate-y-full {
    --tw-translate-y: 100%;
    transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x), var(--tw-translate-y)) rotate(var(--tw-rotate)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x)) skewY(var(--tw-skew-y)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x)) scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y));
}
```

If you want this to work, the css variables other than `--tw-translate-y` have to be defined as well. As mentioned in an [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70005395), you can define those variables by including `@tailwind base`. However, if you don't want to include `@tailwind base` and all the [Preflight base styles](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight) that come with it, you could also define the css variables yourself with some default values:

```css
:root {
  --tw-translate-x: 0;
  --tw-translate-y: 0;
  --tw-rotate: 0;
  --tw-skew-x: 0;
  --tw-skew-y: 0;
  --tw-scale-x: 1;
  --tw-scale-y: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct if you removed `@tailwind base;` and the styles aren't applying it's because the other variables are missing.

If you don't want to apply the global resets, you still keep `@tailwind base;` but in `tailwind.config.js` you disable the preflight (global resets):

```js
// tailwind.config.js

corePlugins: { 
  preflight: false 
}
```

Docs: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#disabling-preflight